# Empty space instead of admin bar

Tags: upgrade

So I upgraded to 3.1 now I have a white band above the header of my website in the frontend when I'm logged in, I know this should be the control menu, but just a white band :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct, that is for the admin bar. add this code to functions.php to disable the admin bar if you wish

```
<?php
/* Disable the Admin Bar. */
remove_action( 'init', 'wp_admin_bar_init' );
?>
```

if you want to use it then check your source for

```
<div id="wpadminbar">
            <div class="quicklinks">
```

If so, then the output is good, After that, it may be css or js conflicts perhaps

Comment: Bingo! Didn't have the wp_footer() hook in my footer!

Answer (score 5):

If you have the white band, but no menu, you are most likely missing the

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

From the bottom of your footer.php, should be just above

```
</body>
```

http://voodoopress.com/2011/02/wordpress-3-1-admin-bar-upgrade-issues/
is a post I'm keeping up to date as I come across things to help people with the admin bar.

Here are some relevant links from the WordPress documentation:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/

Comment: Doh, I see you found the solution..... I missed the little comment there

Comment: No worries, still worth answering and thanks for the link.